# Why can't I use min() on a tuple of doubles in Swift?

Tags: swift, double, tuples, min

```
var coordinatesDouble = (Double(latitudeTextField.text!), Double(longitudeTextField.text!))

var boundingBoxLat: (Double, Double)
var boundingBoxLon: (Double, Double)

boundingBoxLat = (coordinatesDouble.0! - Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight, coordinatesDouble.1! + Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight)
boundingBoxLon = (coordinatesDouble.1! - Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfWidth, coordinatesDouble.1! + Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfWidth)

if min(boundingBoxLat) < -90.0 {
```

I am trying to use min() in an if statement, but am getting the error:

> "Cannot invoke 'min' with an argument list of type (Double, Double)"

I thought this was specifically what this function was for. Am I missing something?

The equation for each double is one double being subtracted or added to another, resulting in a double. The if statement should then be determining if the lowest value in the tuple is lower than -90.0.

Comment: If you have a coordinate, why not use `CGPoint`?

Comment: If you must use a tuple, you must access each element like this: `min(boundingBoxLat.0, boundingBoxLat.1)`

Answer (score 2):

***Am I missing something?***

YES.

Please check this:
[SE-0029 Remove implicit tuple splat behavior from function applications](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0029-remove-implicit-tuple-splat.md)

In the versions of Swift which include this SE-0029, Swift does not accept *a tuple of two members* as an actual parameter for function with *two arguments*.

(There is another overload for `min`, but it's irrelevant here.)

As commented by JAL, you need to pass two arguments to call `min(_:_:)`:

```
min(boundingBoxLat.0, boundingBoxLat.1)
```

---

Some addition.

I wonder if this line is really what you intend:

```
boundingBoxLat = (coordinatesDouble.0! - Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight, coordinatesDouble.1! + Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight)
```

It should be like this, no? (Please find the small difference in the latter half.):

```
boundingBoxLat = (coordinatesDouble.0! - Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight, coordinatesDouble.0! + Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight)
```

But it is not important my guess is right or not. Just you should know that this sort of code using tuples too much is less readable.

I recommend you to define your own structure to represent *boundingBox*:

```
struct CoordinateBox {
    var minLatitude: Double
    var maxLatitude: Double
    var minLongitude: Double
    var maxLongitude: Double

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, height: Double, width: Double) {
        assert(height > 0.0)
        assert(width > 0.0)
        minLatitude = latitude - height
        maxLatitude = latitude + height
        minLongitude = longitude - width
        maxLongitude = longitude + width
    }
}

let boundingBox = CoordinateBox(latitude: Double(latitudeTextField.text ?? "") ?? 0,
                                longitude: Double(longitudeTextField.text ?? "") ?? 0,
                                height: Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfHeight,
                                width: Constants.Flickr.SearchBBoxHalfWidth)

if boundingBox.minLatitude < -90.0 {
    //...
}
```

You would never be confused with `.0`s and `.1`s.

Comment: That's good advice regarding best practices, thank you. Also very interesting note regarding the suggestion of JAL.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple can have different data types mixed together. You should use an array if all the datatypes are the same.